# Web page for uploading a file with HTTP PUT from browser

Tags: html, http

Is it possible to make a web page that would let userr to upload a file to the server using HTTP PUT? 
Which browsers that would work with?

The primary reason for preferring specifically PUT is that it's handled more optimally on the server (i.e. without extra parsing of the request).

I know it's possible at least using a java applet or something similar, but I'm only interested with default configuration of at least some browsers (and preferably without javascript too, if possible).

I have found some mentions of xhtml2.0 (xforms1.1) regarding that, but how to do that is still very unclear to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It can't be done without JavaScript.
- In browsers that do support it, you can make PUT requests with XHR but

  - Support is not universal
  - You can't read files from the user's file system

A POST request is probably the way to go.

> I have found some mentions of xhtml2.0 (xforms1.1) regarding that, but how to do that is still very unclear to me.

Browsers don't support this.

Comment: “can't read files from the user's file system” — does that mean that conventional file upload form that does HTTP PUT instead of HTTP POST for uploading a local file is pretty much impossible?

Comment: No. It means you can't access the files using JavaScript. You can't use PUT as a method in an HTML form for different reasons (those being that no browser supports it and that HTML doesn't suggest that they do)

Comment: This is currently changing with improved [support for HTML 5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible on the server side to accept a PUT request with a script (PHP for example), but it would not make anything *more optimal*. You would still have to check for legal filenames, permissions etc.

Comment: AFAIU it would still be more optimal since permission/... handling can possibly be done before accepting the data and POSTed multiform decoding still doesn't have to be done.  Not sure of the former would be simple with some scripts outside of the scope of the server, but that's unimportant.

Comment: That's the point: you got to have a script waiting for the file on the server side for simple security reasons. Adding a multipart boundary to the request body has virtually no overhead.